# Excel dynamic operations can only be performed in homogenous appdomain error

Tags: c#, .net, excel

The company I work for has the option to create plugins for our main product. I am currently working on a plugin. The plugin needs to read in from an Excel file.

Part of my plugin tries to get a worksheet by name:

```
Excel.Application excelApp = new Excel.Application();
Excel.Workbook wb = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(fileName, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                                         Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                                         Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                                         Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
Excel.Worksheet ws = wb.Sheets[SheetName] as Excel.Worksheet;
```

When I run as a standalone application (outside of our main application) the above code works fine.

However when I run the above code as a plugin from our main application I get the following execption:

```
dynamic operations can only be performed in homogenous appdomain
```

I have done some research and found that the legacy security policy is related. For other reasons that I am unaware of and cannot change our main product must run with legacy security policy turned on.

```
<NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy enabled="true"/>
```

Regardless of this condition our client still wants this feature added. There must be some way of getting the Excel functionality to work.

Comment: dynamic probably refers to the type of wb. more context would be helpful.

Comment: The type of wb is an Excel WorkBook. I'm not sure what other information to provide.

Comment: Not to be snarky, but "Excel Workbook" is not a valid type name. More code around this call could be helpful. How did you get a hold of wb? There are many, many ms and non ms libraries that allow for interacting with excel, so your question is really ambiguous.

Comment: I am using the Microsoft Excel library (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel). I have updated the above code to give more detail.

Comment: I resolved the issue and changed the sample code above. For some reason I had to cast the object coming out of the Sheets collection to a Workbook which for some reason wasn't required in the stand alone application. Also, I had a typo on the type name. It should have been a "." instead of a space like "Excel.Workbook". The type name is "Workbook" in the "Excel" namespace.